# how to estimate $\prod_{k=2}^n \log(k)$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis, products, infinite-product

I wonder if I can estimate $\prod_{k=2}^n \log(k)$ as $a^l$ for some a. I know that it is bounded by $e^{n^2}$, but I would like to get something finer.

Comment: Taking the logarithm and approximating $\sum_{k = 2}^n \log \log k$ may be simpler (you get an easy bound of $e^{n\log \log n}$ from that).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have tried it, I can easily get this bound by writing $\log(k) \leq \log(n)$ for all $2 \leq k \leq n.$ I want to estimate $\sum_{k=4}^n \log \log k$ by $n.$ But the plot of $\frac{\sum_{k=4}^n \log \log k}{n}$shows it is not possible to do.

Comment: Right. But you can also get lower bounds from the sum, and that shows $e^{n\log \log n}$ isn't too badly overestimating (for some values of "too badly"). If needed, you can get better asymptotics from it. We have $\sum_{k = 2}^n \log \log k \sim n \log \log n$. The Euler-Maclaurin sum formula gives more precise estimates.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=\log\log x$ is a concave function on $[2,+\infty)$, since its derivative is $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x\log x}$ and its second derivative is $f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log^2 x}\right)$. The [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) hence gives:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{N}\log\log n \leq \int_{3/2}^{N+1/2}\log\log x\,dx = \left.\left(x\log\log x-\frac{x}{\log x}\right)\right|_{1/2}^{N+1/2}-\int_{1/2}^{N+1/2}\frac{dt}{\log^2 t}$$
and
$$ \exp\left(n\log\log n-\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$$
is a quite good approximation for $\prod_{k=2}^{n}\log k.$

Answer (score 2):

Using geometric and arithmetic mean and Stirlings formula you get
$$
\left(\prod_{k=2}^n\ln(k)\right)^{1/(n-1)}\le\frac{\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k)}{n-1}
=\frac{\ln(n!)}{n-1}\le\frac{\ln(\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)})+n·(\ln(n)-1)}{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{N}1\cdot\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)=\left(N-1\right)\log\left(\log\left(N\right)\right)-\int_{2}^{N}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor -1}{t\log\left(t\right)}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function and using $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t+O\left(1\right)
 $ we have $$=\left(N-1\right)\log\left(\log\left(N\right)\right)-\textrm{Li}\left(N\right)+O\left(\log\left(\log\left(N\right)\right)\right)
 $$ where $\textrm{Li}\left(N\right)$ is the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).